# HTML5 Canvas (Drawing (Rectangle) Keeps Disappearing)

Tags: javascript, iphone, html, canvas

how's it going?

Recently, with the help given from this site, I've learned how to draw a rectangle on an HTML5 canvas at the click of the button... that's not the problem:) The is problem this... unfortunately, every time I click on the canvas to make a new rectangle, the old rectangle disappears (or is instantly erased). It also didn't work at all when I tried to use it on my iPod... why:(?

---

Here's my code:

---

JAVASCRIPT:

```
  // "Rectangle" Button
function rect()
{
var canvas = document.getElementById('canvasSignature'),
    ctx = canvas.getContext('2d'),
    rect = {},
    drag = false;


    function init() {
  canvas.addEventListener('mousedown', mouseDown, false);
  canvas.addEventListener('mouseup', mouseUp, false);
  canvas.addEventListener('mousemove', mouseMove, false);
}


function mouseDown(e) {
  rect.startX = e.pageX - this.offsetLeft;
  rect.startY = e.pageY - this.offsetTop;
  drag = true;
}


function mouseUp() {
  drag = false;
}


function mouseMove(e) {
  if (drag) {
    rect.w = (e.pageX - this.offsetLeft) - rect.startX;
    rect.h = (e.pageY - this.offsetTop) - rect.startY ;
    ctx.clearRect(0,0,canvas.width,canvas.height);
    draw();
  }
}


function draw() {
  ctx.fillRect(rect.startX, rect.startY, rect.w, rect.h);
}


init();
}
```

---

HTML5:

```
<div id="canvasDiv">
    <canvas id="canvasSignature" width="580px" height="788px" style="border:2px solid #000; background: #FFF;"></canvas>
</div>

<div id="rect">  
    <p><button onclick="rect();">Rectangle</button></p>
</div>
```

---

Any help at all would be greatly appreciated:)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have a statement to clear canvas

```
ctx.clearRect(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, that was it lol:) But I'm still wondering... why wont it work on my iPhone?

Comment: Yes, it does work in Safari:) Does that mean it should also be working on the iPhone?

Comment: Apple devices have a limit on bitmap images of 5Mpx. If your canvas is too large maybe this is your issue